# Matplotlib animation save does not create animation for surface plots

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am trying to use matplotlib.animation to animate the time evolution of a surface. A working example is found [on this stackexchange question/answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7030/plotting-a-2d-animated-data-surface-on-matplotlib). Using `plt.show()` I can see the animation fine. The problem is when I try to save it. When saving as either a gif or mp4 I get only one from of the animation. I do not get this problem if I am doing 1d animations, for example using `plt.plot()`. Below is what I am trying:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import cm

def generate(X, Y, phi):
    R = 1 - np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
    return np.cos(2 * np.pi * X + phi) * R

fig = plt.figure()
ax = axes3d.Axes3D(fig)

xs = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50)
ys = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)
Z = generate(X, Y, 0.0)
wframe = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=2, cstride=2, cmap=cm.coolwarm )
ax.set_zlim(-1,1)

def update(i, ax, fig):
    ax.cla()
    phi = i * 360 / 2 / np.pi / 100
    Z = generate(X, Y, phi)
    wframe = ax.plot_surface( X, Y, Z, rstride=2,
            cstride=2, cmap=cm.coolwarm )
    ax.set_zlim(-1,1)
    return wframe,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation( fig, update, frames=10,
        fargs=(ax, fig), interval=100 )

ani.save('plottest3d2.mp4', fps=30)
ani.save('plottest3d3.gif', fps=30, writer='imagemagick')

plt.show()
```

Any help explaining the discrepancy between showing the plot and saving would be great.

Comment: The code is fine, you have to increase the number of frames (100 for example). I believe there's an option "repeat=True" by default in FuncAnimation, but it's not the same when you save it.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that and just did so again by increasing the number of frames to 5000. Still I am getting a gif and mp4 with only one image. Maybe it is something to do with the interval? Are you reproducing a successful gif or mp4 with the above code?

Comment: I changed frames from 10 to 200 and I got a mp4 of 6 seconds length. The rest of the code is the same.

Comment: Just changed to a different computer and it works, so I don't know what is happening. For anyone reading this in the future: I am using ubuntu 14.04 and python 2.7.11 and Anaconda 2.4.1.

Thank you @sebacastroh

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? I use ```1.4.3```, with ```1.5``` I had problems now I remember